# Why won't this cucumber line parse?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have the following simple cucumber step:

```
Given I submit "Father father father help us" in reply to "Where is the love?"
```

I also already have the cucumber step:

```
Given /^I submit "([^"]*)" in reply to "([^"]*)"$/ do |reply, question|
  ...
end
```

Each time I run it though, the question mark at the end sends the parser wobbly and I get back the following:

```
You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given /^I submit "([^"]*)" in reply to Where is the love\?$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Why isn't this parsing correctly and what can I do to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested step definition above doesn't correspond to that Cucumber step. I suspect you have a near-identical step somewhere else in your feature files but without the quotes around "Where is the love?".

Comment: I didn't check closely enough to be certain (while making some other changes) but I suspect this was almost definitely the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I put a quick test together, and here's what i have. It works fine, all tests pass:

```
Feature: test

  Scenario:
    Given I submit "Father father father help us" in reply to "Where is the love?"
    When I do this
    Then I receive that


Given /^I submit "([^"]*)" in reply to "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1, arg2|
  true
end

When /^I do this$/ do
  true
end

Then /^I receive that$/ do
  true
end
```

What version of cucumber are you using? Here's what i have in my Gemfile.lock

```
cucumber (1.0.2)
  builder (>= 2.1.2)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.1.2)
  gherkin (~> 2.4.5)
  json (>= 1.4.6)
  term-ansicolor (>= 1.0.5)
cucumber-rails (1.0.2)
  capybara (>= 1.0.0)
  cucumber (~> 1.0.0)
  nokogiri (>= 1.4.6)
```

Comment: Thanks for runring that. I can't entirely figure out what happened but weirdly when I ran all other specs (not just the one with this tag) everything started to work fine again. As you noted, the whole thing seems to work fine but for some reason something was choking occasionally before.

Comment: Yeah I created this feature and step in an existing rails project with around 30 or 40 defined cucumber steps, and half a dozen features. I ran just this one feature file, and it ran correctly. I know i have had issues with certain nested steps and such if i only run one file.